# Mysql Trigger: Update one row and affect other row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, triggers, database-trigger

I am very beginner in MySQL, I have a table with some data (see below).

How to create some kind of *trigger* on MySQL so that every time I update the `mainPhone` to `"Yes"` the other rows are updated to `"No"`.

```
  id | phoneNumber | mainPhone |
-----+-------------+-----------|
  1  | 08512312334 |    Yes    |
-----+-------------+-----------|
  2  | 08512312323 |    No     |
-----+-------------+-----------|
  3  | 08512312312 |    No     |
-----+-------------+-----------|
  3  | 08512312312 |    No     |
```

Comment: What have you done for this? Can you share your current attempt with us please? :)

Comment: I've always done it using commands from php, but i want to using trigger now

Comment: So you have not tried anything to do this in PHP? To which end - please do some research, try things, and if it breaks, come back with an issue and the code you've tried - we aren't here to do it for you

Comment: in php, i update twice, first i update all mainPhone rows to "No" and secondly i set mainPhone "Yes" by Id

Comment: whether this problem can be solved by trigger in mysql?

Comment: You need to **show** clear research effort and attempts to do this yourself before anyone can help you, we are not here to write it for you

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only one accessing this table then why not update the other rows yourself? When you change the state of one row, update the state of the other ones.

You can do this using the [`NOT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) operator:

```
UPDATE myTable SET mainPhone = "Yes" WHERE condition
UPDATE myTable SET mainPhone = "No" WHERE NOT condition
```